# Modify main loop in taxonomy archive page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop

Is there a way that I can modify the main loop in a single taxonomy template, but leave it untouched in every other template?

In this case, I have a custom post type called "Events" which in turn has a custom taxonomy called "Region". What I want to do is, instead of listing each custom "Events" post chronologically by post date I want to order it by a custom meta value (In this case `event_date`).

I only want to do this in my `taxonomy-region.php` template and leave any other instance of the main loop untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hijack the `$query` just before fetching the posts.

```
function wpdev_156674_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    if (
        $query->is_main_query()
        && $query->is_tax( 'region' )
    ) {
        // Manipulate $query here, for instance like so
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpdev_156674_pre_get_posts' );
```

**References:**

- [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook
- [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class

Comment: Thanks for this, so where would I put my query options (orderby, etc.)? in the `$query->set( 'tax_query', array() );`?

Comment: Yes, just have a look at [the available `WP_Query` methods](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods). I'll update my answer in a minute.